# Unable to schedule more than 1 job in Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have configured calls to 2 method of a class to be called every minute as shown below

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("HK queue test", () => queueChecker.SendToHK(GetQueueCheckerConfiguration(DataCenters.HK)), Cron.Minutely());
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("AS queue test", () => queueChecker.SendToAS(GetQueueCheckerConfiguration(DataCenters.AS)), Cron.Minutely());
```

On the hangfire dashboard however, only one of them shows to be running every minute.

[image]

If I reverse the order of line of code, the reverse happens. When I trigger it manually it works.

I want both of them to run every minute, have I configured it incorrectly?

Comment: Do you use custom queues?

Comment: @mjcs no, I use default.

Comment: If you trigger it manually does it work?

Comment: @mjcs Yes it does work on manual trigger.

Comment: Maybe configure Hangfire to log to a file and see what the exception is?
http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html

Comment: Try waiting for the first job to be created before making the second one, see if that works.

Comment: I think you should use `.Enqueue` instead of `AddOrUpdate`